# smb authentication not working

Tags: authentication, smb

I've recently created a windows file share (SMB).
On linux however, it just says "Unable to mount location Failed to mount windows share" instead of asking for a username & password. On the shares regular users don't have access to it says "The folder contents could not be displayed. You do not have the permission necessary to view the contents of ".
On shares where "everyone" has permissions users can connect without problems.

How do I make it that the linux clients (Ubuntu 12.04) can enter their password when accessing a limited access share instead of just getting an error message?

Answer (score 0):

You can add the credentials when mounting a SMB share.

For example:

> mount.cifs -o user=test,password=secret //192.168.123.123/Data /mnt